# PHP - how to write if its a multiple 4 + 2

Tags: php

How do I work out if my $count is a multiple of 4 + 2?

Every time my count goes through a loop I want to do something when it is equal to 6 | 10 | 14 | 18 | 22 etc...

I'm trying `if(($count + 2) % 4 == 0)`. But this doesn't seem to work and i'm not very good at maths, to be honest.

Comment: you mean (a multiple of 4) + 2, or a multiple of (4 +2) ?

Comment: why don't you store the count in another variable like `$another = $count + 2` and use that in if condition.

Comment: if you wanted to start at 6 and then every 4 just set your count to 6 to begin with then + 4 each loop

Comment: may be the count start from 1 and start check from 6.

Comment: Seems to work, https://eval.in/573793, no? Can you describe `doesn't seem to work`? Are you getting an error, white page, etc?

Comment: Sorry it works now, i just placed it in the wrong segment of my code aha

Answer (score 1):

```
for ($k = 0; $k <= 20; $k++) {
    if ($k % 4 == 0) {
        var_dump($k + 2);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement, try to change your original logic to if(($count - 2) % 4 == 0). this should be want you want?

Answer (score 1):

I understand you want a generic loop and specific action for some values.

```
for ($count = 0; $count <= $myLimit ; $count++) {
    // Do something every iteration...
    if ($count >= 6 && ($count - 2) % 4 == 0)){
        // Do something if 6 | 10 | 14 | 18 ...
    }
}
```

Comment: This seems like the right answer to the question, but you don't need to check if count >=6, it will return false on `($count - 2) % 4 == 0)` anyways.